# Bidirectional RNNs?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm trying to reproduce a paper, and I need a bidirectional LSTM, is it possible in v11.1.1? I don't see anything in the documentation for using a bidirectional GatedRecurrentLayer[] or LongShortTermMemoryLayer[].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can construct one easily using `SequenceReverseLayer`. There is an example in the documentation under that function:

```
binet = NetGraph[{BasicRecurrentLayer[10], BasicRecurrentLayer[10], 
   SequenceReverseLayer[], 
   CatenateLayer[2]}, {NetPort["Input"] -> 1 -> 4, 
   NetPort["Input"] -> 3, 3 -> 2 -> 4}]
```

[image]